# Indie science fiction film - ragtag team searching a planet to place an artifact

Tags: story-identification, movie

In the prologue sequence at the beginning of the movie, it explains that there were 11 or 12 races of aliens at war, but now there are only 3. As the movie progresses, it follows a ragtag team searching the planet to place an artifact. I distinctly remember it was directed by an Asian man.

Comment: When did you see this movie, and when do you think it might've been made? Also, can you describe any of the main characters or aliens in a bit more detail?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.